# Excel IF function across multiple rows and columns at the same time

Tags: excel

I manage a student housing apartment building and have my rent roll within a excel document. In my property, residents are able to lease at multiple rent levels (whole unit, room within unit, or bed within the room). I am looking to be able count the number of "Vacant" rooms if both of the beds within the room are labeled "Vacant".

Column C has the unit number

Column D has the room number

Column E has the bed number

Column F has the resident's name

Unit 923(C1)
room1(D1)
Top(E1)
John Doe(F1)
Bottom(E2)
Vacant(F2)
room2(D3)
Top(E3)
Vacant(F3)
Bottom(E4)
Vacant(F4)

In this case, unit 923 is a two bedroom unit with four beds (two in each room). Room 1 is partially occupied by John Doe and is therefore not available at the room level. Room 2 has both of the beds "Vacant", so it is available to be rented out at the room level.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My quick fix was to add an additional column(G*) and enter the formula: =IF(AND(AND(G3="Vacant"),AND(G4="Vacant")),1,0).  This works if I go through my whole document and only paste within the same row as the Top bed. If I apply the formula to G2, it counts as 1 because the top bed in the following room is "Vacant" It would be nice if I was able to apply a formula to the whole column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest logic with AND and OR to figure it out:

IF x AND y => true if both x and y are true

IF x OR y => true if either x or y are true

IF x AND (y OR z) => true if x is true and either y OR z is true

[See here](http://www.bluemoosetech.com/microsoft-excel-functions.php?jid=19&) for some examples.  [Here is a more formal explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Truth_table)

Comment: Thanks mikeb!  I ended up with this formula: =IF(AND(AND(F3="VACANT"),AND(F4="VACANT",AND(D4=""))),1,0)

Comment: You don't need an AND when there is only one parameter. =IF(AND(F3="VACANT",AND(F4="VACANT",D4="")),1,0)

Answer (score 0):

I added an additional column G to contain the results of the IF function. My final formula is:

=IF(AND(AND(F3="VACANT"),AND(F4="VACANT",AND(D4=""))),1,0)

I just add the new column's values for the number of available bedrooms.